# Sum weeks for month totals formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this excel sheet picturee below.  I'm trying to get the sums of the weeks in the column of the month using a sumif or sumifs but keep returning 0.  Here is the forumala I've used.  Any ideas?

Thanks

```
=SUMIF(B6:B50,">=1/1/2013 && <=1/31/2013",E6:E50)
```

Here is the picture of the excel sheet [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B6:B50>=DATEVALUE("1/1/2013"))*(B6:B50<=DATEVALUE("1/31/2013")),E6:E50)
```

Comment: is there any way to dynamically change the date values.  I this works great but I have 8 more sheets starting from 2004 and changing the date value of 1/1/2013 to the correct year and month will take longer than the actually import in to the database

Comment: maybe I don't understand you correctly, but you can change `DATEVALUE("1/1/2013")` to `Date(2013,1,1)`

Comment: Yea...its I have years 2005 - 20013 and each is broken down into an excel sheet for one year just like the screen shot above.  In order for this to work for january my forumla looks like : =SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$59>=DATEVALUE("1/1/2005"))*($B$6:$B$59<=DATEVALUE("1/31/2005")),$C$6:$C$59) but for it to work for february have to change that datevalue to 2/1/2005

Comment: try to change `DATEVALUE("1/1/2013")` to `DATEVALUE("1-" & I$5 & "-2013")` where `I$5` contains `Jan`

Comment: like this `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$50>=DATEVALUE("1-" & I$5 & "-2013"))*($B$6:$B$50<=DATEVALUE("31-" & I$5 & "-2013")),$E$6:$E$50)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `SUMIFS` should work...

```
=SUMIFS($E$6:$E$50,$B$6:$B$50,">=1-"&I$5&"-2013",$B$6:$B$50,"<=1-"&I$5&"-2013")
```

Put that in the `Jan` column and when you switch sheets, just change the year, so that you have to change only the year when you change sheet.

Using `&&` in `SUMIF` doesn't work, you you need `SUMIFS` to be able to `AND` criteria.